# How does the Flash and PSRAM work together parallelly?

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, embedded

I have used ESP32 microcontrollers for a while now and mostly the schematics I have seen so far have data and CLK pins the same for Flash and PSRAM; only the chip enable pin is different. How do they work together?

[image: Here is one schematic from the chip manufacturer's reference design]

Answer (score 2):

As @justme answered, the chip selects control which device is active.

Fundamental to SPI is that unless the chip select is asserted to a target device, that device ignores clock and data-in and leaves data-out floating. Thus, if chip-select is unasserted, the device is effectively not connected.

Answer (score 1):

They work because they have different chip selects. The MCU can and will communicate only with one chip at the time on the SPI bus.